# Нормализация данных из HTTP-запроса по типу данных в БД

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js

Я часто сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией, когда нужно в контроллере перед записью в БД проверить некоторые приходящие данные на соответствие типу данных в БД, будь то длинна строки, пустота или null, и др. Сейчас у меня все данные в любом случае проходят проверку на xss/sql-injections, а вот после этой проверки я хочу запилить такую штуку:

- При запуске сервера (если передан нужный параметр естественно), читаем нашу БД, все таблицы в ней (конкретно нас поля интересуют).
- На основе прочитанного, генерим классы для проверки входных данных (они то и будут обрезать строки если они оч длинные, приводит пустую строку к NULL если нужно, и тд.)
- И уже в нужном контроллере, мы можем проверить данные которые пришли:

  `//в этот момент REQ.body уже прошел проверку на xss`
  `dataChecker.check(REQ.body,'db_table_name');`

Собственно, вопрос в том, **хорошо это или нет**? Может стоит сделать например XML-конфиги, а из них уже генерить классы, в которых можно будет например проверять не все поля на соответствии тому что в БД (ведь в некоторых случаях для нас не имеет значение содержание некоторых полей). **Или есть более умное решение для подобных задач?**

P.S. Сам наверное больше в сторону варианта с XML склоняюсь...

Comment: По-моему тут попытка сделать работу, которую должна делать ORM. Ну и термин "проверка на xss/sql-injections" намекает на непонимание сути проблемы и отсутствие экранирования, хотя могу ошибаться

Comment: И да, строки обрезать не надо: пользователь сильно обидится, если набранный им длинный-длинный текст просто возьмёт и пропадёт. Надо выдавать ошибку валидации

Comment: @andreymal, ну вы бы предложили варианты решения

Comment: Погуглить ORM и экранирование)

Comment: @andreymal, а при чем тут экранирование? Если мне надо для некоторых типов автоматически присвоить null если была передана пустая строка. Наверное вы не поняли суть вопроса

Comment: Экранирование - это он видимо про инъекции говорил. А проверять на sql инъекции не надо, надо просто делать запросы с параметрами. Если запрос с параметрами, то есть инъекции, или нету - БД без разницы. Ну разве что вы хотите злоумышленников ловить.

Comment: @Dmitry, ну я делаю запросы вида 'SELECT FROM 'users'.'u' WHERE 'u'.'id' = ?.  То я имел ввиду фильтрацию на всякие html-сущности и тд. А вы можете объяснить как завязать структуру бд с моделью? в новом ответе если можете (хотелось бы понять как это сделать без использования sequelizejs  и тп)

Comment: Увы мне, боярин, я только по БД (в основном по ораклу).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае самое умное решение - не конструировать очень странный велосипед, а использовать [какую-нибудь библиотеку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_ORM-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA) доступа к данным, которая умеет всё что вам нужно (и даже гораздо больше), гораздо надёжней и быстрее.

Comment: Я почитал обо всем и подумал, что ORM это слишком большой импрув для моего велосипеда, вы не могли бы подсказать, как сделать сведение данных к тому виду, в котором они должны записаться в бд? (основываясь на предположениях которые я описал)